# How do I extract all the values of a specific key from a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that all have the same structure within the list.  For example:

```
test_data = [{'id':1, 'value':'one'}, {'id':2, 'value':'two'}, {'id':3, 'value':'three'}]
```

I want to get each of the `value` items from each dictionary in the list:

```
['one', 'two', 'three']
```

I can of course iterate through the list and extract each value using a for loop:

```
results = []
for item in test_data:
    results.append(item['value'])
```

however my data set is quite large.  I'm wondering if there's a faster way to this.

Comment: I can't imagine it would get much faster than that. You're looking at each dictionary one time, and a dictionary has immediate lookup. If you want to increase speed to a substantial degree, you'd need to change to a different structure, probably.

Comment: A list comprehension should be slightly faster.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you just need to iterate over the values once, use the generator expression:

```
generator = ( item['value'] for item in test_data )

...

for i in generator:
    do_something(i)
```

Another (esoteric) option might be to use `map` with `itemgetter` - it could be slightly faster than the generator expression, or not, depending on circumstances:

```
from operator import itemgetter

generator = map(itemgetter('value'), test_data)
```

And if you absolutely need a list, a list comprehension is faster than iterated `list.append`, thus:

```
results = [ item['value'] for item in test_data ]
```

Comment: In most cases I would use the generator, but I believe that I need the entirety of the list.  I'm going to try out the list comprehension to see if that speeds things along.

Answer (score 12):

You can do this:

```
result = map (lambda x:x['value'],test_data)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data is truly large, a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) will be more efficient:

```
list((object['value'] for object in test_data))
```

ex:

```
>>> list((object['value'] for object in test_data))
['one', 'two', 'three']
```

The generator portion is this:

```
(object['value'] for object in test_data)
```

By wrapping that in a `list()`, you exhaust the generator and return its values nicely in an array.